# Implementing until as a macro

Tags: clojure, macros

Here's my failed attempt:

```
(defmacro until
  [condition body setup increment]
  `(let [c ~@condition]
    (loop [i setup]
      (when (not c)
        (do
          ~@body
          (recur ~@increment))))))

(def i 1)

(until (> i 5)
  (println "Number " i)
  0
  (inc i))
```

I get: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't let qualified name: clojure-noob.core/c

I am expecting this output:

`Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4
Number 5`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues with the macro:

- You need to generate symbols for bindings inside macros. A convenient way to do this is suffix the names with `#`. Otherwise the bindings in your macros could overshadow bindings elsewhere in your code.
- Some of the macro inputs were unnecessarily *spliced* when unquoted i.e. `~@` instead of `~`

Here's a version of the macro that will compile/expand:

```
(defmacro until [condition body setup increment]
  `(let [c# ~condition]
     (loop [i# ~setup]
       (when-not c#
         ~body
         (recur ~increment)))))
```

But this will loop forever in your example because `condition` is only evaluated once and `i`'s value would never change anyway. We could fix that:

```
(defmacro until [condition body increment]
  `(loop []
     (when-not ~condition
       ~body
       ~increment
       (recur))))
```

And we need to make `i` mutable if we want to change its value:

```
(def i (atom 1))

(until (> @i 5)
  (println "Number " @i)
  (swap! i inc))
;; Number  1
;; Number  2
;; Number  3
;; Number  4
;; Number  5
```

But now `until` is starting to look a lot like the complement of `while`, and its extra complexity doesn't seem beneficial.

```
(defmacro until [test & body]
  `(loop []
     (when-not ~test
       ~@body
       (recur))))
```

This version of `until` is identical to `while` except the test is inverted, and the sample code above with the atom still behaves correctly. We can further simplify `until` by using `while` directly, and it'll ultimately expand to the same code:

```
(defmacro until [test & body]
  `(while (not ~test) ~@body))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am just confused about one point now: how come your first working example is working without the @ symbol at ~body yet the second one requires it?

Comment: @AdamSilver `body` is a single expression in the first couple examples, but it's a list of expressions in the latter examples. Note the `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `let` line too:

```
... 
`(let [c# ~@condition]
...
```

Then rename all references of `c` to `c#`. The postfix `#` generates a unique, non-namespaced-qualified identifier to ensure that the symbol created by the macro doesn't clash with any existing symbols in the context that the macro expands into. Whenever you bind a symbol in a quoted form, you should be using `#` to prevent collisions, unless you have a good reason to not use it.

Why is this necessary in this case? I can't remember exactly the reason, but if I recall correctly, any symbols bound in a syntax quoted form (`` `() ``) are namespace qualified, and you can't use a `let` to create namespace qualified symbols.

You can recreate the error by typing:

```
(let [a/a 1]
  a/a)
```